# Understanding a basic matrix theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

There's a theorem in Linear Algebra which says that if ${\bf A}$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $m < n$, then the homogeneous system of linear equations ${\bf A}{\bf X}=0$ has a non trivial solution.

I read a proof but what happens if I have a matrix like ${\bf B}$, whereas

B =        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        \end{pmatrix}

For ${\bf B}$, $m < n$ but the only solution for ${\bf B}$ is the trivial one, unless I am getting something wrong, which I suspect and I would appreciate a lot if you help me find what is it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=[x \ y \ z \ w]^T$ and consider the equation $BX = 0$. Because of the way your B-matrix looks, this only pins the value of $x$ to $0$. Any $X=[0 \ y \ z \ w]^T$ will do as a solution, and if, in particular, you choose on of $y,z,w$ to be nonzero, you have a non-trivial solution.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        1\\
        \pi \\
        e
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        0  \\
        0 \\
        0 
        \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: The theorem applies only for non-degenerate matrices.

Comment: What is a non-degenerate matrix?